# How to suppress all warnings using MSBuild

Tags: command-line, msbuild

How would I suppress all warnings (or at least as many as possible since those prefixed with MSB cannot be suppressed [How to suppress specific MSBuild warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023858/how-to-suppress-specific-msbuild-warning))?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best way is to fix the issues that are causing the warnings.

If you must ignore the warnings (e.g. you have inherited a project with so many that you can't see the wood for the trees), you could try changing the WarningLevel property, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13b90fz7.aspx

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what happened! Also, the way software is released here requires that non-developers build from the software repositories and I want warnings to be suppressed for them.

But yes, when the time presents itself the issues will be fixed.

Comment: Can you add an example rather than just linking to an external site?

Comment: this is `csc` compiler CLI and it can't be used in MSBuild `msbuild -warn:0` raises error like `unknown option`

Comment: `msbuild /property:WarningLevel=0` [hides](https://learn.microsoft.com/uk-ua/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN) all compiler warnings (besides MSB*). I'm using it in the Azure build pipeline to reduce msbuild log. Thinking is `/clp:ErrorsOnly` good to be used in pipeline (it hides everything besides errors)

Answer (score 83):

**msbuild  /clp:ErrorsOnly**

```
  /consoleloggerparameters:
                     Parameters to console logger. (Short form: /clp)
                     The available parameters are:
                        PerformanceSummary--Show time spent in tasks, targets
                            and projects.
                        Summary--Show error and warning summary at the end.
                        NoSummary--Don't show error and warning summary at the
                            end.
                        **ErrorsOnly--Show only errors.**
                        WarningsOnly--Show only warnings.
                        NoItemAndPropertyList--Don't show list of items and
                            properties at the start of each project build.
                        ShowCommandLine--Show TaskCommandLineEvent messages
                        ShowTimestamp--Display the Timestamp as a prefix to any
                            message.
                        ShowEventId--Show eventId for started events, finished
                            events, and messages
                        ForceNoAlign--Does not align the text to the size of
                            the console buffer
                        DisableMPLogging-- Disable the multiprocessor
                            logging style of output when running in
                            non-multiprocessor mode.
                        EnableMPLogging--Enable the multiprocessor logging
                            style even when running in non-multiprocessor
                            mode. This logging style is on by default.
                        Verbosity--overrides the /verbosity setting for this
                            logger.
```

Comment: This might not work if you want to suppress a specific warning. E.g. in my case, I would like to suppress warning MSB3270.

Comment: Surprisingly helpful documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx

Comment: It looks like this doesn't work if you're using msbuild in an Azure Devops context, as it uses the `/dl` parameter (distributedlogger) to capture logs in a way that doesn't respect the `/clp` settings, and there are no corresponding `/dlp` settings.

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to suppress MSB3270 only then you can set in project file just

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>
    None
  </ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

## In Jenkins

- Happened upon this Googling "how to suppress MSBuild warnings in Jenkins"
- So much noise like the following in our console output, couldn't find the meat

  ```
  Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member
  ```
- Inherited Jenkins on a Windows server

---

1. Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration > MSBuild
2. Add **`/clp:ErrorsOnly`** to the **Default parameters**
   [image]

Comment: This works for `dotnet build /clp:ErrorsOnly` too. While it is not a good idea to hide warning messages this can help clear up the CI logs.