# Supressing msbuild compiler warnings

Tags: c++, msbuild

I'm trying to build a Visual-Studio solution from the command line with msbuild, however the compiler spams some 30.000 warnings into the log. It is not my codebase and I don't intend to fix the warnings.

How can I disable the warning output? I found some suggestion to use the flag

```
/clp:ErrorsOnly
```

However this will suppress anything but errors, even the standard build output. Also, verbosity level of msbuild will not affect warnings. How can I get a clean output again?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm The duplicate you postet contains the solution which I stated wouldn't work in my case, and secondly a solution which seems to work only with C#

Comment: OK.  [Not a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050826/how-to-suppress-all-warnings-using-msbuild).