# Build a VS2003 project from the command line without outputting warnings

Tags: command-line, build, command-line-arguments, tfsbuild, visual-studio-2003

Anyone know if it's possible to build a VS2003 project from the command line without showing any warnings? We've got a heap of VS2003 projects that get built by TSFBuild as part of our platform build and the warnings are just noise in the build log file.

I have looked at the parameters by running devenv.com /help and nothing there seems relevant. VS2010 has a build output verbosity setting but I couldn't find one for VS2003. I am also looking to see if it can be configured through the project file.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're building your projects using MSBuild. If so, you can try suppress the warnings by setting the WarningLevel property as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023858/how-to-suppress-specific-msbuild-warning). Or you can choose the console logger to not show the warning and error summary, then output them to seperate files as provided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> /consoleloggerparameters:parameters
>
> **NoSummary**: Hides the error and warning summary displayed at the end
>   of a build.
>
> /fileloggerparameters:
>
> You can use up to ten file loggers by
>   following the parameter with a digit
>   identifying the logger. For example,
>   to generate separate log files for
>   warnings and errors, use -
>   /flp1:logfile=errors.txt;errorsonly
>   /flp2:logfile=warnings.txt;warningsonly

Comment: Unfortunately it's a little more complicated than that. MSBuild can't natively build VS2003 solutions so we're using vs2003 command line to build the project. I don't think MSBuild knows what part of the devenv output is warnings because it's not affected by the /verbosity switch in the same way the 2010 solutions are.

Comment: Useful to know about being able to log different types of errors differently though. Thanks very much for that.