# Suppressing C#-specific warnings in a solution that contains both C# and VB.NET projects

Tags: msbuild, suppress-warnings

We use TFS 2010 for server builds. I would like to turn some of the less useful warnings off. I can achieve that by specifying custom MSBuild arguments:

```
/p:NoWarn=1591
```

It works for a solution with C# projects. However, we have one solution that also has some VB.NET projects in it. VB.NET compiler doesn't have the warnings that C# compiler has, so I get the following error message:

> vbc: warning number '1591' for the option 'nowarn' is either not configurable or not valid

Is there a way to achieve this for solution that include projects in several .NET languages without specifying list of ignored warnings separately for every project in the solution?

Comment: You should be able to configure this per project, it's not a solution-wide setting, just like you can from the VS IDE itself. Or is this a web site where sources in different languages are part of the same web site?

Comment: @Abel: I know that I can configure this per project, however, I would like to a) avoid specifying this settings in 30+ projects inside the solution and b) have the ability to only turn them off for server builds

Comment: Check if this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023858/how-to-suppress-specific-msbuild-warning

Answer (score 0):

BC* warnings can't be suppressed. Your best option is to reevaluate the `NoWarn` property in VB projects using the `BeforeCompile` target, by editing the `.vbproj` files:

```
<Target Name="BeforeCompile">
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(NoWarn)' == '1591' ">
    <NoWarn>42016,41999,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036,42020,42021,42022</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```