# Disable/Prevent XUnit Warnings on build in .NET Core Test Project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit, xunit.net

I have a project with several large test cases in it and the project takes about 2-3 minutes to build. I am suspicious that it has to do with this new warnings feature... for example:

> warning xUnit2003: Do not use Assert.Equal()
>   warning xUnit2004: Do not use Assert.Equal() to check for boolean conditions.

It is doing this for thousands of lines...

It would be great if there was a way to disable this feature. Not sure if it has to do with the visual studio runner or xunit itself.

Comment: How about fixing your unit tests and using `Assert.IsTrue` and  `Assert.IsFalse` instead?

Comment: Technical debt has a way of calling in the loan. You need to fix the tests. The warnings are there for a reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could disable the warnings as follows:

- for a file

  ```
  #pragma warning disable xUnit2003, xUnit2004
  ```

  optionally restore them:

  ```
  #pragma warning restore xUnit2003, xUnit2004
  ```

Or in your project properties:

[image]

Comment: no way to do this on the command line?  :/

Comment: @johnk see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023858/how-to-suppress-specific-msbuild-warning