# How to disable warning MSB4011 in Visual Studio (property sheets included 2+ times)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I use property sheets to manage inclusion of header and library dependencies. In the dependency tree, a project might end up including a property sheet twice, if 2 dependencies share a common dependency (and that's because property sheets can include other propery sheets).

Which results in:

> warning MSB4011: "xxx.props" ne peut pas être réimporté car il a déjà été importé. Cette importation est ignorée.
> (already imported, ignored....)

This is just a warning but I would like to disable it. How ?

I tried compiler option:

> /nowarn:MSB4011

> /nowarn:4011

Doesn't work.

I tried pragma:

> #pragma warning( disable : 4011)

Doesn't work.

Comment: Don't have msbuild in this tablet ... but are you sure the option is spelled "norwarn" not something like "nowarn"?

Comment: I know that there is the `/wd` option.  That's what my projects are using.  For example `/wd"4011"`  But that's the C++ compiler.

Comment: @ÖöTiib good catch. That said it still has no effect with `nowarn`

Comment: @Joe i'm using msvc; I tried `/wd"4011"` which seems the correct way to do this, but has no effect. The warning id is `MSB4011` and if I try `/wd"MSB4011"` I get "numeric argument not valid". I think MSB stands for "microsoft build", it's not a C++ warning even tho I'm compiling c++ code.

Comment: Just to be sure, go to the property page of the actual *project* being built to be sure that the property sheet settings are actually getting there.  It's possible that you can set a setting in a property sheet and then the project that includes it just completely overrides the setting.  So go to the project (not the sheet), right click and choose "Properties".  The under C++, look at the "Command line" setting and be sure that you truly see your option in there.    If not, got to "Advanced" (again under C++) and look at "Disable Specific Warnings"

Comment: Just did that and disabled warning 4011 and it has no effect. The issue is that `4011 != MSB4011`. It's not a C++ warning it's a MSBuild warning (it's tied to the visual studio IDE). I think I just can't remove this warning.

Comment: Is this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63724725/16764520) useful?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT didn't help unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

Suppressing the warning level with /p:WarningLevel=X might be a way, other than that, there doesn't seem to be a way: [related thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/96b3ea2e-92ed-4483-bbfe-a4dda3231eb9/suppress-msb4126?forum=tfsbuild). I suggest to propose a new feature (suppress MSB warning) to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=62&entry=suggestion). You can put the link in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

How about good old Include-Guard?
In the importing Projects:

```
<Import Project="my_global_defs.props"
        Condition="'$(MyGlobalDefs_Version)'==''" />
```

and in the imported Project:

```
<PropertyGroup Label="IncludeGuard" >
  <MyGlobalDefs_Version>1.0</MyGlobalDefs_Version>
</PropertyGroup>
```

`:´(`  OK, the importer must know the name of the include-guard.
But it works.